# Why is this function a bijection?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider the function below

$$f:\mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$$ given by $$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$$.

Now it makes sense that the function is injective because $f(x) = f(y) \implies \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} \implies x = y$.

However, I am kinda shocked that the function is surjective.

let $b \in \mathbb{R^+}$. Now I need to show that there exists an element $a$ also in $\mathbb{R^+}$ such that $b = \sqrt{a}$. It is like saying that every element in $\mathbb{R^+}$ can be written as a square root right !

So if I take $a$ to be $b^2$ then I am done because $\sqrt{b^2} = b$ and that's about it to prove surjectivity and hence bijectivity ?

I am confused because, how you can you represent an element in the positive reals like $\pi$ using a square root ! It will never be accurate !

Comment: Why not? $\pi = \sqrt{\pi^2}$.

Comment: Ok I guess I got it now !! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you suggest is sufficient for surjectivity. While it is true that you could not work out the decimal expansion of numbers like $\pi^2$ by hand in any finite amount of time, $\pi^2$ is a positive real number, so $\sqrt{\pi^2}=\pi$. The real numbers are unsettlingly complicated. Trying to work with the decimal expansions of real numbers can be messy, but we can still deal with them abstractly.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it may be best to simply try your hand at a proof and then inspect it to see where you might be going wrong, if anywhere. For example:

**Claim:** The mapping $f\colon\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is bijective.

*Proof*. We must show the mapping to be both injective and surjective:

**Injective:** Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then:
$$
f(x_1)=f(x_2)\\[0.5em]
\sqrt{x_1}=\sqrt{x_2}\\[0.5em]
x_1=x_2.
$$
Thus, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is injective.

**Surjective:** Suppose $x=y^2$. Then:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sqrt{x}\\[0.5em]
&= \sqrt{y^2}\\[0.5em]
&= y.
\end{align}
Thus, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is onto.

Since the mapping $f\colon\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is both injective and surjective, it must be bijective by definition, concluding the proof. $\blacksquare$

---

Did you see any problem with the proof of surjectivity? Hopefully not--it shows that every number is the square root of something, and that is what you need to show for a mapping to be surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $I = \{ x > 0 \mid x^2 > b \}$, which is bounded from below. By the completeness of $\mathbb R$, $I$ has an infimum, which will be the square root of $b$.

Comment: But the task was not to show that every number has a square root, but tha every number is the square root of something.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you are right. I hasn't read it properly :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show that $f : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is a bijection is to find an inverse function $g$.

So define:

- $f(x) = x^{1/2}$
- $g(x) = x^2$

Now simply prove that $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}$ and $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}.$

For maximum rigor, I recommend defining that $p^x$ means $\mathrm{exp}(x \log p),$ whenever $p \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In this case:

- $f(x) = \mathrm{exp}(\frac{1}{2} \log x)$
- $g(x) = \mathrm{exp}(2 \log x)$

Comment: Showing the existence and the properties of $\exp$ and $\log$ are much more complicate than showing the existence of square roots.

Comment: @user251257, but the existence of $\exp$ and $\log$ and their basic properties are treated in painstaking detail in many texts, so I feel completely comfortable taking these for granted. What we don't want to do is leave things to geometric intuition. That's really the most important thing.

Comment: Yes, but usually square root comes before $\exp$ and is much more elemental. For $\exp$ you need series or functional equations.

Comment: @user251257, I don't recommend defining square roots before defining $\exp$. This would be an unnecessarily painful way of establishing basic real analysis!

Comment: It just one sentence using the order completeness of $\mathbb R$. For the existence of $\log$ you need the complete theory of continuous and monotonic functions. That's an overkill.

Comment: @user251257, but then you have to prove that the function you just defined really is an inverse of squaring. And honestly, I think your critique is pretty silly. Before you can even do basic mathematics, you *have* to establish the existence of $\exp$ and $\log$, as well as their basic properties. You have absolutely no choice in the matter. So why not get the existence of $x$th roots for free, as an immediate corollary? We *have* to stop creating more work for ourselves than is strictly necessary. These kind of distractions make me embarrassed for the state of mathematics. Its like when...

Comment: textbooks have the reader carry out pointless exercises just to make the point that a completely straightforward theorem can be proved, after much pain, without all the usual machinery. I find this tiresome, even *embarrassing.*

Comment: $\inf \{  x > 0 \mid x^2 \ge b \}$ is clearly the square root of $b > 0$ given the continuity of squaring. Anyway that's little bit off topic.